# understanding the hashing system and algorithm?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography, password-protection, password-encryption

I  want to how hashing algorithms works, I mean in salt hashing the same plaintext generates multiple hashes so when the app stores one hash when user register and then he logged in now there are 2 different hashes in the register and log in how the app compares theses 2 hashes? and validating this user?

Comment: There is only one hash stored, the salted one that is computed at registration time. When the user attempts to login, he presents his password and the application takes it, retrieves the salt, and hashes the salt together with the presented password. If the resulting hash matches the stored one, the password is assumed to be correct and the user is authenticated. A specialized password hash is used, for example bcrypt.

Answer (score 0):

The salt is added and stored in the database along with the Hash value.
So this stored salt can be used later in the verification process.

This is on of the best explanations for the Salt cryptography
https://blog.conviso.com.br/worst-and-best-practices-for-secure-password-storage/[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3UZZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hash algorithms, informally, are deterministic random numbers. Deterministic means for an input the hash value never changes. Random in a sense that you can predict without calculating it.

To prevent against rainbow tables; in basic form, salt is added to passwords. The salt must be random for each user.

In the database, you store the salt and Hash(salt|passwd) in two columns.

```
|username   | Salt Columns    | Hashed password Column   |  
| Alf       | 0x819313134144  | 0x783184187Fba1123313    |
| Charlie   | 0x83bf521ad922  | 0x39849ffd61e44123277    |
```

When a user enters the passwd into the system, the application server gets the salt from the database, calculates Hash(salt|entered_passwd) and compares with the Hash(salt|passwd) that was stored in the password.

If there is a match the login is successful.

If you are looking a way to protect your password look at [argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) the winner of [password hashing competition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_Hashing_Competition)